# angularjs export to csv extra character when viewed on notepad

Tags: angularjs, csv, export-to-csv

I'm exporting a ng-table to a csv file. It works when I open the file on Excel but when I use notepad, it has some extra characters in the beginning of the file. Particularly, this "sep=," characters.

Example:

`sep=,
"Corporation","Date"
"ABC Company","20 Oct"
"XYZ Company","21 Oct"`

This is my code:

```
<div class="panel-body">        
<table ng-table="reportTable" class="table table-striped" export-csv="csv">         
    <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="data in $data">                        
        <td data-title="'CORPORATION' | translate" sortable="'corpName'">
            {{data.corpName}}</td>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
        <td data-title="'DATE' | translate" sortable="'formattedDate'">
            {{data.formattedDate}}</td>                                                                                                                                                                                         
    </tr>               
</table>

<a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click='csv.generate($event, "{{reportType}}.csv", reportTable)' href=''  
    ng-show="reportData.length > 0">
    <i class="fa fa-download fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;<span data-ng-bind="'EXPORT_TO_CSV' | translate">
</a>
```

How can I get rid of this extra characters?
Thanks!

Comment: where does `csv.generate` method comes from? available overloads?

Comment: it's from ng-table http://ng-table.com/#/

Comment: the documentation is quite limited.. have you tried some workaround? Remove first element from the export data structure? Like `reportData.shift()` before exporting it?

Comment: removing the "sep=," from the ng-table-export.js somehow still exports correctly to excel, so is to notepad. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

tried removing the "sep=," from the ng-table-export.js and somehow still exports correctly to excel, so is to notepad.